# Proving a Proposition about separable Hausdorff spaces that are locally euclidean

Tags: general-topology, separable-spaces

Let X be a separable Hausdorff space such that for every $x \in X$ there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Show that:

(i) $X$ is locally compact

(ii)there exists a countable compact cover of $X$.

My attempt:
(i)
Suppose $x \in X$ and U to be an open neighborhood of $x$. Then there exists an open subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a homeomorphism $\phi: U \rightarrow V$.
$V$ is an open neighborhood of $\phi(x)$ and we can find an open ball with radius $r$, $B_r(\phi(x))$ such that $B_r(\phi(x)) \subseteq V$. Now,the closed ball with radius $r/2 $ $\overline{B_{\frac{r}{2}}(\phi(x))}$ is a compact neighborhood of $\phi(x)$ and since $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, $\phi^{-1}(\overline{B_{\frac{r}{2}}(\phi(x))})$ is a compact neighborhood of $x$ in $X$. Thus, X is locally compact.

(ii):
Approach 1:
I know that if $X$ is second countable, then any open cover of X, has an open countable subcover.
But $X$ isn't a second countable space. So this could be the wrong approach.
(Question: Is there a way to show that $X$ is second countable?)

Approach 2:
If $X$ is separable, there exists a countable dense subset $D$ such that $\overline{D}=X$. Since $X$ is locally compact, we can choose a compact neighborhood $C_d$ for $d \in D$.
If $X \subseteq \cup_{d \in D} C_d$, then we are finished.
That's how far I got.

Is there a way to prove (ii) (maybe with a different approach)?

Comment: Number 2 is false.  Note first that for a Hausdorff locally-Euclidean space, being $\sigma$-compact is equivalent to being second-countable.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold#Properties).  Second, a separable such space does not have to be second-countable.  See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56275) for a reference to a counterexample.

Comment: Also, in part 1, note you need to take $U$ which is homeomorphic to an open set in $\Bbb{R}^n$.  Not *every* neighborhood of $x$ has this property.  Just there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the $\pi$-Base can help with these sorts of questions:

1. https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/?q=Separable%2B%24T_2%24%2BLocally+%24n%24-Euclidean%2B%7ELocally+Compact

All locally euclidian spaces are locally compact: https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000332/

2. https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/?q=Separable%2B%24T_2%24%2BLocally+%24n%24-Euclidean%2B%7ESecond+Countable and https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/?q=Separable%2B%24T_2%24%2BLocally+%24n%24-Euclidean%2B%7Esigma-compact

In this case the $\pi$-Base doesn't know if such spaces are $\sigma$-compact or second countable.

From https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%24T_2%24%2BLocally+%24n%24-Euclidean%2B%7E%24%5Csigma%24-compact we see that the separable condition will be necessary.

From https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Separable%2BLocally+%24n%24-Euclidean%2B%7E%24%5Csigma%24-compact we see the Hausdorff condition would be necessary.

From https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%24T_2%24%2BSeparable%2B%7E%24%5Csigma%24-compact we see that the locally euclidian property would be necessary. From https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Separable%2B%24T_2%24%2BLocally+compact%2B%7ESecond+Countable we see that locally compact is an insufficient replacement.

---

One counterexample is described in [the link from Chad K's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56275). I was unable to find a peer-reviewed verison of the Gauld paper cited, but [in 1990 Mary Ellen Rudin published a ZFC example which was $T_4$, separable, locally Euclidean, but not metrizable](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686419090099N). Note that in this context, $\sigma$-compact, second countable, and metrizable are all equivalent. (I haven't worked through the details, but should note that she explicitly asserted that this space is both normal and Hausdorff.)

Comment: Thank you for your help.